# Service Discovery dies after wifi disconnect / reconnect

Tags: c#, connection, wifi, bonjour, dns-sd

why does losing a wifi connection or using flight mode break service discovery until power cycling the adapter or rebooting?

Steps to recreate issue :

Run Dns-sd -B "_services._dns-sd._udp.local." *~Returns all Services*

**Turn on Flight Mode**

*Discovered Services Removed*

**Turn off Flight Mode**

*Services not added back in*

**Close cmd prompt**

**open new cmd prompt**

Run Dns-sd -B "_services._dns-sd._udp.local." *~returns no services*

**restart Bonjour Service**

Run Dns-sd -B "_services._dns-sd._udp.local." *~returns no services*

**Disable Wifi Adapter**

**Enable Wifi Adapter**

on windows 10 Run Dns-sd -B "_services._dns-sd._udp.local." *~Returns all Services*

Issue also occurs on win 8 with the same hardware.

Code is c# , dns-sd is being used to test the system ,  the following open source packages have been tested :

zeroconf c# https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf)
*~ Same issue*

Mono-zeroconf c# (https://www.mono-project.com/archived/monozeroconf/)
 *~ same issue*

mdns browser (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdns-browser/kipighjpklofchgbdgclfaoccdlghidp) *~ Works , I have no idea why.*

On some setups (router - adapter - os) there is no problem on others it just doesn't not work over a connect / reconnect.

On a failing setup I have found 1 usb wifi adapter that will work out of about 20.

one of the non working adapters has a device property called Radio on/off , if I use this instead of flight mode then it does work.

there is no real consistency in why it doesn't not work , no errors , warnings or any key issues

Comment: You have not managed to 'ask a question' in your post.  Consider editing your post to include a specific question.